# Estoy llamando a una tabla para que se muestre en pantalla y me da error con el fetchAll

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetchAll() in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_1\log in\listar.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_1\log in\listar.php on line 5

el siguiente es el codigo:

```
<?php 
    include_once("conexion.php");

    $sentencia = $conex->query("SELECT * FROM buses;");
    $buses = $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    print_r($buses);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

El error te indica lo siguiente:
Call to undefined method **mysqli**_result::fetchAll()
Esto significa que no encuentra el metodo fetchAll.

En el código que usas tienes lo siguiente:
$buses = $sentencia->fetchAll(**PDO**::FETCH_OBJ);

[PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.php) y [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) son dos maneras distintas de hacer consultas a la base de datos.

El metodo que más se acerca a lo que estas intentando para mysqli sería el metodo [**mysqli_result::fetch_array()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Podrías intentar lo siguiente:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM buses;"
$consulta = $conexion->query($query); //Conexion sería tu conexión a la base de datos, pon como la hayas llamado tu.
$resultado = $consulta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); //Aquí ya tendrías las filas que te devuelve la consulta.
```

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias extensiones para conectar la base de datos en PHP. Las más usadas son [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) y [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro.pdo.php).

Cada una tiene **sus propios métodos** y su propio estilo y no hay que confundirlos, que es lo que ocurre en tu pregunta, pues usas `fetchAll()` que es un método de `PDO`, en una conexión basada en `mysqli`.

El método para obtener los resultados en forma de objeto en `mysqli` es [`fetch_object()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php).

Hay que subrayar también que hay dos tipos de métodos *fetch*, uno que te trae todas las filas de golpe que es `fetchAll` (PDO) / `fetch_all` (mysqli) y los que te traen las filas una por una ([revisa en el Manual los diferentes métodos fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php)). En `mysqli` el método `fetch_all` sólo está disponible cuando tienes instalado el controlador `mysqlnd`.

Sea como sea, no conviene usar el método que te trae todos los registros cuando se esperan muchas filas, porque la memoria podría verse desbordada.

Dicho todo eso, tu código podría escribirse de dos maneras:

#### Trayendo fila por fila

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM buses;";
$allRows=array();
if ( $stmt = $conex->query($sql) ) 
{
    while ( $obj = $stmt->fetch_object() ) 
    {
        $allRows[]= $obj;
    }
}
var_dump($allRows);
```

#### Trayendo todas las filas de golpe

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM buses;";
$allRows=array();
if ( $stmt = $conex->query($sql) ) 
{
    $allRows = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
var_dump($allRows);
```

Como dije más arriba, para que esta forma funcione debes tener instalado el controlador `mysqlnd`. Por otra parte, con `fetch_all` no puedes asociar los resultados como objetos.